# Bootstrap Carousel removing items and indicators problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel containing 10 or so items with indicators. The indicators are also clickable and can scroll to each item when clicked e.g. data-slide-to="1" attributes are applied to the elements. The carousel works as expected with no problems.

I now need to remove items on some condition. When i try to remove an item from the carousel that is NOT currently active my javascript runs and my carousel still works perfectly.

However If the item i want to remove is currently active this is when the carousel stops working after the item and indicators are removed. I understand that there always needs to be an "active" item which is why i call carousel.('next') if the active item is the one to be removed.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what i need to do next to resolve this please. (Also when i remove an item should my indicators be automatically removed).

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$('#Container').children().each(function (index, item) {
 var id = item.id;
 if (!eventData.evList.some(ev => ev.ev_no == id)) {              
            var carElement = $('.carousel').find('#' + id);
            if ($(carElement).hasClass('active')) {
                $('.carousel').carousel('next');
            }   
            carElement.remove();            
            $('#' + id + 'ind').remove();
            $('#evIndicators').children().each(function (index, item) {                
                    $(item).attr('data-slide-to', index);               
            });          
        }        
});
```

```html
<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide pointer-event">
    <ol id="evIndicators" class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-top: -50px; height: 50px; float: left;">
        <li id="2245ind" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active">22</li>
        <li id="2315ind" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">23</li>
        <li id="2345ind" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2">24</li>
    </ol>
    <div id="Container" class="carousel-inner">
        <div id="2245" class="carousel-item active">
            <a id="22451" class="btn-link" href="#" onclick="showAddDialog(22451,8,1)">   
                <div class="runnerNum">1</div>         
            </a>            
        </div>
        <div id="2315" class="carousel-item">
            <a id="23151" class="btn-link" href="#" onclick="showAddDialog(23151,9,1)">
    <div class="runnerNum">1</div>                
            </a>            
        </div>
        <div id="2345" class="carousel-item">
            <a id="23451" class="btn-link" href="#" onclick="showAddDialog(23451,10,1)">    
                <div class="runnerNum">1</div>                
            </a>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

});

22:45
        23:15
        23:45
    
    
        
                     
                1         
                        
        
        
            
                1                
                        
        
        
                            
                1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have to wait until the slide i initiated had to complete before i did the actual deleting/removing of the slide panel and indicator. I fixed it by the doing the following.

create an removeId global variable and set carousel element (carElement) a global variable.

```
$('#Container').children().each(function (index, item) {
 var id = item.id;
    if (!event.evList.some(ev => ev.race_no == id)) {
       removeId = id;
       carElement = $('.carousel').find('#' + id);
       if ($(carElement).hasClass('active')) {
          $('.carousel').carousel('next');
       }
    }                    
 });
```

Then use the carousel "slid" event that runs every time a slide finishes and check if we have a candidate carousel element that we need to delete...then remove the element and indicator.

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    if (carElement) {
        carElement.remove();
        $('#' + removeId + 'ind').remove();
        $('#evIndicators').children().each(function (index, item) {                    
            $(item).attr('data-slide-to', index);                    
        });
        carElement = null;
        removeId = null;
   }
});
```

Now i don't know if this is the best way of fixing this as it looks a bit messy to me. I'd be happy for someone to help improve my code. Thanks.